# How to implement multi tenant feedback or rating system?

Tags: database, php

How to implement multi-tenant feedback or rating system?

I just need to centralize all types of feedback gathering application where my client will signup on my website and select service for their firm(Hotel, Healthcare, GYM, Parlour whatever sector he belongs to).

The problem is that some client need rating based feedback(e.g. Star rating wise), someone needs survey-based questions list and their rating option in front of every question.

So, please suggest me to solve this complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/), a modern CMS, and written in PHP. It can be used to build virtually any kind of websites, and for sure also for what your question is about.

These days there are typically 2 releases of it being used:

- Drupal 7, very mature, and zillions of contributed modules (plugins to add specific facilities to a site), release around 2011.
- Drupal 8, pretty new, first beta release dates from late 2014. Major new facilities includes in its core version, but still missing lots of contributed modules (which haven't been upgraded from Drupal 7 yet).

Combine this with some contributed modules that address your specific needs, such as:

- the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module.
- the [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) module.
- the [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) module.
- the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module.
- ... (incomplete list).

Checkout the above links to get the big picture ...